# Removing single raster from ArcGIS Raster catalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, raster-catalog

I have duplicate rasters in a raster catalog which I want to remove. There is no tool to remove single rasters.

Is there another way to do this without removing the entire raster catalog and reloading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open ArcCatalog rather than the Catalog tab in ArcMap.
Using the Catalog Tree browse to the geodatabase that contains your raster catalog and then single click on the raster catalog.

[image]

In the contents Tab in ArcCatalog you will then see a long list of all the rasters held in this catalog.  You can right click on a raster and select "Delete".

[image]

You can hold down the "Shift" or "Ctrl" keys on your keyboard while selecting rasters to select multiple rasters before deleting them.